# How to access list of dictionary in Django template

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates, jsonparser

I am very new to Django and implemented a post-api call by watching couple of tutorials and one of the fields gets a list of dictionaries, want to access the key value pair in Django template, instead it is taking char by char, do I have to change the definition in models.py for the `Message` field or use `JSON parser` in views.py ?how to solve this problem?

models.py

```
class Leads(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Mobile = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Message = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

Example input for above api call will be:

```
   Name = rakesh
   Mobile = 1234567890
   Email = email@mail.com
   Message = [{'key': 'some text', 'value': 'some value'}, {'key': 'some text', 'value': 'some value'}]
```

This is how my api records are getting stored in Database

views.py

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def userLeads(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            Name = request.data['Name']
            Email = request.data['Email']
            Mobile = request.data['Mobile']
            Message = request.data['Message']   

            datainsertion = models.Leads(Name = Name, Email = Email, Mobile = Mobile,Message= Message)
            datainsertion.save()
            content = {'Leads_Status': 'Created'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        content = {'Order_Status': 'Failed'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_424_FAILED_DEPENDENCY)
```

Views.py

```
def chat_Leads_view(request):

    user_list = models.Leads.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    myFilter = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=user_list)
    user_list = myFilter.qs
           
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(user_list, 5)
    
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
        
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
        
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    
    segment = 'leads'
    context = {
        "users": users,
        "segment":segment,
        "myFilter":myFilter
        
    }   
    
    return render(request, "leads.html", context)
```

template.html

```
   {%for user in users %}
     <tr>                                                
         <td>{{user.Name}}</td>
         <td>{{user.Mobile}}</td>
         <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
         <td>{{user.Message}}</td>
     </tr>
   {%endfor%}
```

If I try like above then the output is

```
rakesh  1234567890  emaik@mail.com  [{'key': 'some text', 'value': 'some value'}, {'key': 'some text', 'value': 'some value'}]
```

If I add another loop for `Message` field then the `Message` field is not showing any output:

```
   {%for user in users %}
     <tr>                                                
         <td>{{user.Name}}</td>
         <td>{{user.Mobile}}</td>
         <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
   {%for i in user.Message %}
         <td>{{i.key}}</td>
         <td>{{i.value}}</td>
   {%endfor%}
     </tr>
   {%endfor%}
```

Output:
displaying string by string

```
rakesh  1234567890  emaik@mail.com
```

If I try like this then:

```
{%for user in users %}
         <tr>                                                
             <td>{{user.Name}}</td>
             <td>{{user.Mobile}}</td>
             <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
       {%for i in user.Message %}
             <td>{{i}}</td>
       {%endfor%}
         </tr>
       {%endfor%}
```

Output:

```
rakesh  1234567890  emaik@mail.com  [ { ' k e y ' : ' s o m e t e x t ' , ' v a l u e ' : 's o m e v a l u e ' }, { ' k e y ' :  ' s o m e t e x t ' , ' v a l u e ' : ' s o m e v a l u e ' } ]
```

The way I want in Django template is:

```
rakesh  1234567890  emaik@mail.com  key:value 
                                    key: value
```

Comment: Your message is a string, since it originates from a CharField, not a list, dictionary, etc.

Comment: Yes, any idea how to change it in models.py?

Comment: work with a `JsonField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message is not a list of dictionaries. It is simply a string that contains some data that *looks* like a list of dictionaries.

You probably should change it to a [**`JsonField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField):

```
class Leads(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Mobile = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Message = models.JSONField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and re-populate the database with data. In that case accessing the message will indeed return a list of dictionaries that you can then render with:

```
<td>
{% for item in user.Message %}
    {{ item.key }}<br>
    {{ item.value }}
{% endfor %}
</td>
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Lead` instead of <s>`Leads`</s>.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `message` instead of <s>`Message`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Comment: I got following error : message =  models.JsonField()
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'JsonField'

Comment: @Bharath: what version of Django do you use?

Comment: @Bharath: it was a typo: it is `JSONField` instead of `JsonField`.

Comment: I am using Django=3.2.4 and still getting the same. if you observe I have value also as a key (the keys I have are key and value) and the actual values are some text)

Comment: @Bharath: exactly what is `type(request.data['Message'])`? when you enter data?

Comment: <class 'str'> I am gettinig

Comment: @Bharath: well then you send it as a string to the API endpoint, but you should send it as a JSON blob.

Comment: @Bharath: exactly how does the client looks like that makes the POST request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236019/discussion-between-bharath-and-willem-van-onsem).